# Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I am new to recursion and binary trees. I am trying to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/) on leetcode.

To find maximum sum path is like finding maximum path between any two nodes, that path may or may not pass through the root; except that with max sum path we want to track sum instead of path length.

My algorithm is passing 91/93 test cases and I just can't figure out what I am missing. Can anyone please provide some direction?

```
class Solution {
    private int sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        maxPathSumHelper(root);
        if(root.left != null){
            maxPathSumHelper(root.left);
        }
        if(root.right != null){
            maxPathSumHelper(root.right);
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
    public int  maxPathSumHelper(TreeNode root){
        if(root ==  null){
            return 0;
        }
        //check left sum
        int leftValue = root.val + maxPathSumHelper(root.left);
        if(leftValue > sum){
            sum = leftValue;
        }
        //check right sum
        int rightValue = root.val + maxPathSumHelper(root.right);
        if(rightValue > sum){
            sum = rightValue;
        }
        //check if root value is greater 
        if(root.val > sum){
            sum = root.val;
        }
        //check if right and left value is the greatest
        if((leftValue + rightValue - (2 * root.val) )+ root.val > sum){
            sum = (leftValue + rightValue - (2 * root.val)) + root.val;
        }
        return Math.max(leftValue, rightValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: To me the task looks more like a max-sum-subtree, not a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
class Solution {
    private int sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        maxPathSumHelper(root);

        if (root.left != null) {
            maxPathSumHelper(root.left);

        } else if (root.right != null) {
            maxPathSumHelper(root.right);

        }

        return sum;
    }
    public int  maxPathSumHelper(TreeNode root) {
        if (root ==  null) {
            return 0;
        }

        //check left sum
        int leftValue = root.val + maxPathSumHelper(root.left);

        if (leftValue > sum) {
            sum = leftValue;
        }

        //check right sum
        int rightValue = root.val + maxPathSumHelper(root.right);

        if (rightValue > sum) {
            sum = rightValue;
        }

        //check if root value is greater
        if (root.val > sum) {
            sum = root.val;
        }

        //check if right and left value is the greatest
        if ((leftValue + rightValue - (2 * root.val) ) + root.val > sum) {
            sum = (leftValue + rightValue - (2 * root.val)) + root.val;
        }

        return Math.max(Math.max(leftValue, rightValue), root.val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess we can a bit simplify our statements here.

This'll simply get accepted:

```
public final class Solution {
    int max;

    public final int maxPathSum(final TreeNode root) {
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        traverse(root);
        return max;
    }

    private final int traverse(final TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        final int l = Math.max(0, traverse(node.left));
        final int r = Math.max(0, traverse(node.right));
        max = Math.max(max, l + r + node.val);
        return Math.max(l, r) + node.val;
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/discuss) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: This does not seem to take the negative node values into account, does it?

Comment: @Emma thank you for simplifying my complicated statements and taking the time to provide the steps. Although I see a similarity in the  logic of the statements, I am still trying to figure out what comparison I am missing that is throwing the algorithm off. can you perhaps help me with this - please and thank you.

Comment: @Suman thanks I think I was missing the fact that either the leftsum or rightsum or left + right + root should be returned. I think i get it now. Thank you both Emma and Suman. Both solutions help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
 def numDecodings(self, s: str) -> int:
   if s[0] == '0':
    return 0

   dp = [[0, 0] for i in range(len(s) + 1)]

   dp[0][0] = 1
   dp[1][0] = 1

   for i in range(1, len(s)):
    # zero must be second
    if s[i] == '0':
      if s[i-1] not in ['1', '2']:
        return 0
      dp[i+1] = [0, dp[i][0]]

    elif '00' < s[i-1:i+1] < '27' and s[i-1] != '0':
      dp[i+1] = [sum(dp[i]), sum(dp[i-1])]

    else:
      dp[i+1] = [sum(dp[i]), 0]

  return sum(dp[len(s)])
```

Try this code using Python 3 format at Leetcode you will passed..